# Visual studio error microsoft.vshub.server.httphostx64.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2015, runtime-error, windowserror

Every time that I work with Visual Studio 2015 I get the same error,

> microsoft.vshub.server.httphostx64.exe stopped working.

[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vHyr.png).

Answer (score 2):

This is a common bug with 2015, not sure if it's hotfixed  but this will fix it.

Stop Visual Studio if started
rename C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub\1.0.0.0 Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe to Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe.bak
Create a copy of Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost.exe and rename it Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe
Re-start Visual Studio

That should fix it